# Either of them will be fine. / Either of them is fine. / I would like either of them

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Are there any of the following answers wrong and why? How do you usually answer that question if there is a need to answer especially politely?

> Would you like a piece of cake or a candy bar?

> **Either of them will be fine.**
>
> **Either of them is fine.**
>
> **I would like either of them.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context *fine* means good or satisfactory and would be deemed offhand. So your first two sentences would be more suitable when choosing, say, a ladder.

At my politest I'd probably say, 'Thank you. I'd like either.' More effusively I might prefix an 'Ooh!' or a 'How lovely!' or both.